# How to add a relationship in a pre-existing table using SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a table with several columns and I want to add a new relationship using SQL Alchemy. As I have many columns, I can't create an object mapping all columns and just adding the relationship. I need a way to automatically load all columns and add a new relationship.

Example :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'sqlite',
    'database': 'test.db'
}

engine = sa.create_engine(URL.create(**DATABASE))
Base = orm.declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    # ...Assume multiple other columns here

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...Assume multiple other columns here

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = orm.Session(engine)

user1 = Parent(id=1, name='Jorge')
user2 = Parent(id=2, name='Lucas')
user3 = Parent(id=3, name='Amanda')

child1 = Child(id=1)
session.add_all([user1, user2, user3, child1])
session.commit()
```

Now, in another session, I want to load the table Child and add the relationship. How can I do that?

Example (what I tried and didn't work):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'sqlite',
    'database': 'test.db'
}

engine = sa.create_engine(URL.create(**DATABASE))
Base = orm.declarative_base()

class Child(Base) :
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = orm.relationship("Parent", uselist=False, backref="child")
```

ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class Child->child could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'child'

Example two :

```
class Child(Base) :
    __table__ = sa.Table('child', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
        
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = orm.relationship("Parent", uselist=False, backref="child")
```

ArgumentError: Can't add additional column 'parent_id' when specifying **table**

Comment: Does `child` have a `parent_id` column already?

Comment: Assume no. But adding only that is a simpler “ADD COLUMN” problem. Main issue is really adding the relationship

Comment: Does the `Parent` model exist in the "other" session?  If it does is it imported or redefined?

Comment: I think this is part of the answer. Is the ```Parent``` model needed? In the examples I tried, I didn't use it, but if you come up with a solution where a ```Parent``` model is imported or redefined, let's have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

1- First of all, the column `parent_id` needs to be created on the Child table in the database if it's not created before, and of course the relationship needs to be populated. This is a simple "ADD COLUMN" problem

2- On the new session where the database is explored/editted, we have to add only the relationship object inside the Classes (any type of relationship):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'sqlite',
    'database': 'test.db'
}

engine = sa.create_engine(URL.create(**DATABASE))
Base = orm.declarative_base()

class Parent(Base) :
    __table__ = sa.Table('parent', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    
class Child(Base) :
    __table__ = sa.Table('child', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    
    parent = orm.relationship("Parent", backref="child")
```

...that way, we can easily query the database with the relationship added :

```
session = orm.Session(engine)
parents = session.scalars(sa.select(Parent)).all()
```

And each `parent` will have a `child` object associated according to the previously mapped parent_id in the table